# File not found in Cron, Works Perfectly By browser

Tags: php, cron

I'm a bit at a loss - for some reason I cannot get my cron job to execute a file correctly, well, actually, it executes the file but cannot find the file to include. If I execute it via the browser directly the file gets included.

I have the exact same script on 4 other accounts on the same server with the same cron command to run every 5 minutes (which all 4 work perfectly).

I get cPanel to send me the report when the cron job has been executed and get the following:

```
Warning: include(../../../init.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/***/public_html/***/_scripts/php/cron.php on line 5
```

The file 100% exists - all files have the same ownerships and are all CHMOD to 0644 - so am a bit lost why the cron cannot find the file, even though it does exist

The cron command is as follows (and is the same on the other 4 sites):

```
php -q /home/***/public_html/***/_scripts/php/cron.php
```

Comment: use full path in cron jobs

Comment: the command has the full path, and the other 4 sites work like this successfully - surely they should all either work or all not work - doesn't make sense!